# Multiply two vectors with dimensions increasing along time

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix-multiplication

I have two vectors (called `A` and `B`) with length `N`. Then I need to multiply both of them, but as an "integration" process. Which means I have to multiply first `A(1)*B(1)`, then `A(1:2)*B(1:2)`, until `A(1:N)*B(1:N)`. The result of multiplying booth vector is a number, since `B` is a column vector. I've done it with a `for` loop:

```
for k = 1:N
    C(k) = A(1:k) * B(1:k).';
 end
```

But I wanted to ask you if this is the best solution or there is any other option more time-efficient, since `N` is very large (about `110,000`)

Comment: It looks like C = cumsum(A.*B). Is this correct?

Comment: yeah, kind of. But what I need is that, for example if A=[1 2 3] and B= [1 1 1], the result of C should be C=[1*1  1*1+1*2   1*1+1*2+1*3  ]=[1 3 6]. Doing what you said I get a matrix N*N, where each column is the expected result. But If I do that I will get a huge matrix, since my N is very large.

Comment: @Navan's suggestion doesn't produce an NxN matrix, it returns a vector? `A=[1 2 3]; B=[1 1 1]; C=cumsum(A.*B)` returns `C=[1 3 6]` as requested... Good answer Navan

Comment: Thanks Wolfie. Pep, you may get different answer if A and B have different orientation. Make sure both are row vectors or both column vectors.

Comment: To make @Navan answer more general just write: `C = cumsum(A(:).*B(:)`, and you good to go.

Comment: Yeah! my mistake, it's correct you answer, tank you so much @Navan!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C = cumsum(A.*B)
```

does the same thing without for loop. As EBH suggested in the comments if you are not sure whether A and B have same orientation, then use

```
C = cumsum(A(:).*B(:))
```